# Wrong behavior of "not" in SPARQL filter with equals and bound

Tags: filter, sparql, equality

I found strange behaviour of "not" in filter inside sparql. To demonstrate i prepare simple example here is data:

```
@prefix tst:      <http://data.test.org/resource/ontology/tst#> .
@base             <http://data.test.org/resource/ontology/tst> .

tst:Item1
    a                              tst:Book ;
    tst:relatedArticle               tst:Article1 ;
    tst:author   tst:Author1  .

tst:Article1
    a                                     tst:Article ;    
    tst:author        tst:Author1 .

tst:Item2
    a                              tst:Book ;
    tst:relatedArticle               tst:Article2 .

tst:Article2
    a                                     tst:Article .
    
tst:Item3
    a                              tst:Book ;
    tst:relatedArticle               tst:Article3 ;
    tst:author   tst:Author1  .

tst:Article3
    a                                     tst:Article ;    
    tst:author        tst:Author2 .

tst:Item4
    a                              tst:Book ;
    tst:relatedArticle               tst:Article4 ;
    tst:author   tst:Author1  .

tst:Article4
    a                                     tst:Article .

tst:Item5
    a                              tst:Book ;
    tst:relatedArticle               tst:Article5  .

tst:Article5
    a                                     tst:Article ;    
    tst:author        tst:Author1 .
```

There are 5 items with type Book, each realted to each own Article. Book and Article have author, so i want to find all items where author not match. So i add simple request

```
PREFIX tst: <http://data.test.org/resource/ontology/tst#>
SELECT  ?itemId
WHERE
  { ?itemId   a      tst:Book
    OPTIONAL
      { ?itemId tst:author  ?bookAuthor}
    OPTIONAL
      { ?itemId tst:relatedArticle/tst:author ?articleAuthor}
    FILTER ( ! ( ( ( ! bound(?bookAuthor) ) && ( ! bound(?articleAuthor) ) ) || ( ?bookAuthor = ?articleAuthor ) ) )
  }
```

And it return ONLY item3, ok i think may be i miss something in filter so i removed "!" in filter, e.g. everything is same except now its:

```
...FILTER ( ( ( ( ! bound(?bookAuthor)...
```

And this return what i expect item1 and item2 which is OK.
But why if i want to invert this filter and use ! it not return item3, item4, item5, but only item3?
What is happening?

Iam able to do what i need with using "minus {...}" construct, but i really dont understand what is wrong with filter.

Comment: why do you think it should return `item4` and `item5`? You're negation does negate the whole filter expression, by multiple application of De Morgan law this leads to `FILTER (
  ( 
  ( 
   ( bound(?bookAuthor) ) 
   || 
   ( bound(?articleAuthor) ) 
  ) 
  
  && 
   ( ?bookAuthor != ?articleAuthor ) 
   ) 
 )`

Comment: the first part of the conjunction (`&&`) requires that at least one of `?bookAuthor` and `?articleAuthor` has to be bound. BUT: the second part requires that `?bookAuthor != ?articleAuthor` - and here is the point, if one of both variables is not bound, then this part leads to **error** and in fact to `FALSE`. Now check for example `item4`: it has an author but its related article does not have an author, thus, `?bookAuthor != ?articleAuthor` is **error**, thus, `FALSE`

Comment: "?bookAuthor != ?articleAuthor is error, thus, FALSE"
Ok imagine it is FALSE, then first part also FALSE because for item4 "(!true && !false)", so whole filter inside "!(...)" will be "false or false", and then "!(false)  -> true", so item4 should be showen.
And "not" applied to construction inside () so it should be evaluated first and then reversed.

Comment: " if one of both variables is not bound, then this part leads to error and in fact to FALSE. "
No this is not true, it will leads to some another state which not converted to boolean and just somehow removed from result set. That is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found cause of it, its not in boolean algebra, its related to how SPARQL handle compare between unbound values.
It is in fact will be in some "unbound" boolean state, which not produce error, and NOT prevent whole boolean from calculation only if it is not required. BUT if this "unbounded" state required to calculate whole boolean, it will be NOT false, but make whole boolean "unbounded" and it cant be inverted or anything.
For better illustration check picture.
[image: example]